# Prove the convergence and calculate the limit of $A_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n²}, n \in N \,\ and \,\ n\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

**Task:** 
Prove the convergence and calculate the limit of $$A_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n²},
n \in N  \,\ and \,\ n\to\infty$$

Hello, it is my first question here on math.stackexchange, therefore my formatting skills are not the best ones, I apologize for this. 
I have problems calculating the limit and proving the convergence of $A_n$.
I appreciate your help.
Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: for given $\epsilon$ let $N\geq [\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}]+1$

Answer (score 0):

One has: $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^*,|A_n|=\frac{1}{n^2}.$$
Therefore, one has: $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}|A_n|=0.$$
From there, $(A_n)$ is convergent to $0$.